# Is there an Qt Tools addon for MS Visual Studio 2017 Proffesional?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2017

Is there an official addon for MSVS Proff 2017 of Qt Tools?
Thank you for verified links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSVC 2017 Qt addin can be found on https://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/.

The last released version is 2.2, see http://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/02/26/qt-visual-studio-tools-2-2-0-released/ for the release announcement.

Comment: Thanks. I can append link from ms web: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools-19123

Comment: All works. I found newer version qt-vsaddin-msvc2017-2.2.1_45e1490.vsix which works.

Comment: NB: The Qt VS Tools are designed to work with Qt5. Previous versions of Qt are not supported.